# android studio - drawable file option synchronize - what is it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I notice in android studio there is an option to synchrnize a drawable.  Right click on a drawable and you'll see the following:

[image]

why would i want to do this ? what does it mean ? is it the same as doing a clean build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Synchronize` option checks **external** changes from your file system in case they were not detected automatically by the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is for synchronization purpose of that file. e.g. You edited file somewhere out of android studio and changes to that file doesn't affect in android studio, then you can synchronize it to get the result.